# Where to write python code in anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I have downloaded the anaconda distribution for the python but now I didn't find that where to write python programs like I was writing python code using python IDLE. Please help me to get rid of this problem

Thanks in Advance :)

P.S:- I only have anaconda and I have not downloaded python from its website or I don't have any previous versions of python installed on my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options of how to write and execute python code using anaconda. One simplest way is to simply type `python` inside your Anaconda Prompt (the command line). This will open up an interactive python interface where you can type python code and have them executed line by line.

If you want to write longer python code, it's best to type your python code in any text editor and save your code as a `your_code_name_here.py` file and then in the Anaconda Prompt navigate to the folder you saved the `.py` file and type `python your_code_name_here.py`. This will execute the full body of your code.

Alternatively, the Anaconda distribution comes with the Spyder IDE (interactive development environment). You should be able to find Spyder in your programs and that should be quite intuitive to use since you are used to using an IDE.

Comment: Okay ! Thank you very much !